# Unity3D: Vertices and Edges of a plane aren't showing

Tags: unity-game-engine, vertices, plane

I'm fairly new to Unity3D here, and I can't seem to find the answer to this question anywhere. So I created a cloth stimulation of a plane, but I can't see the vertices and edges on the plane (as in the grid of lines). It probably is a trivial question with a simple answer, but I can't find an answer, so I need help! Thank you.

[image: Here is a Screenshot]

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean. Are you asking how to "turn on" some kind of debug draw tool that draws points that represent the verts?

Comment: You image is on the Game tab, can you try on the Scene tab?

Comment: I found what I needed! In the scene tab, right in the tool bar in the upper left are modes to view the scene. What I wanted was a wireframe, and the mode was there.

Comment: @The3DSquare you are welcome!